# Removing an Object when it hits another object AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

Beginner here. I have a symbol on the timeline with an instance name of 'island', so basically I want to remove the cells that hits the 'island'

```
if (cell.hitTestObject (island)) {

             if(stage.contains(cell))
             removeChild (cell);
         }
```

I tried this one under the moveCell function but it only removes one cell instead of every cell that hits the island. Thanks everyone!

Here's my code so far:

```
 package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var cell:Cell;
        public var group:Array;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;


        public function Main() {

            cell = new Cell (400, -15);
            addChild (cell);

            group = new Array();
            var newCell = new Cell (100, -15);
            group.push ( newCell);
            addChild(newCell);


            gameTimer = new Timer (25);
            gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,moveCell);
            gameTimer.start();
        }

        public function moveCell (timerEvent:TimerEvent):void {

             if (Math.random() < 0.01) {
             var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 700;
             var newCell:Cell = new Cell (randomX, -15);
             group.push (newCell);
             addChild(newCell);
             }


         for each(var i:MovieClip in group) {
             if (i.hitTestObject(island)) {

                i.visible = false;
                //i.parent.removeChild(i); 

                var score:int = 0;

                 score ++;

                scoreOutPut.text = score.toString();



             }   
         }



        }

    }

}`
```

Comment: You should do the hit test with all your `group` array items using a `for` loop ...

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for replying! I created a for loop but i'm now having an error that says "DisplayObject must be a child of the caller." It'd be awesome if you could help me please. Here's the code:

 for each(var i:MovieClip in group) {
     if (i.hitTestObject(island)) {
      
      stage. removeChild(i)
      
     }

Comment: You can write `i.parent.removeChild(i);` to avoid that error ...

Comment: I tried it but now I get an error saying "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." I tried "i.visible = false;" it worked it's just that im not sure if that's the proper way to go?

Comment: Could you add your whole code to your question, it will be more easy to see the problem ?

Comment: Hi again, sorry to bother you, I really appreciate it! did u mean the for loop? or the other class? I've added the for loop bit. I've also included a score counter but it's stuck at 1 and wouldn't increase at all when cell hits the island. Much appriciated

Comment: I've never actually used splice before so I'm not sure what to write... Could you please write the whole for loop please. 
As for the score, does that mean i have to make a new function under this class? Do I need an event listener for it? Sorry I'm not very good at this yet

Comment: Forget my last comment about splice, I'll put a little answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" because you've removed the `Cell` object from the `DisplayObjectContainer` (its parent) but not from the `group` array, so in the next iteration of your `for` loop, that object didn't exist anymore and that error will be fired.

To avoid that you can do like this :

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < group.length; i++)
{               
    var cell:Cell = Cell(group[i]);
    if (cell.hitTestObject(island))
    {
        cell.parent.removeChild(cell);
        group.splice(i, 1);     
        score++;
    }
}
```

For the `score`, it should be a global property for all your class to get updated every time.

Also, for your code to be more organised and clearer, it's better to put every task in a single method.

For example, for creating cells, you can use a `createCell()` method :

```
// 0 is the default value of __x and -15 is the default one of __y
private function createCell(__x:Number = 0, __y:Number = -15): void 
{
    var cell:Cell = new Cell(__x, __y);
    group.push(cell);
    addChild(cell);
}
```

Then you can use it in any place in your code, for example, for your two first cells that you create in the constructor :

```
public function Main()
{
    // ..

    createCell(400);
    createCell(100);

    // ...
}
```

Or inside the `moveCell()` method :

```
if (Math.random() < 0.01)
{
    var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 700;
    createCell(randomX);
}
```

Also, if you don't really need that a property or a method to be `public`, don't put it as public.

...

Hope that can help.

Comment: You are so nice! Thank you soooo much. Everything works perfectly!! Have a nice day/night!