# Still got error #2025 even when I think I've fixed it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an as3 code which control when the mc `hitTestObject` a `Sprite` object, it removes that `Sprite`.

I got error #2025 when I run it but only when I hit one of 20 `Sprite` (I made 20 `Sprite`s in the beginning).

Here's the code :

```
if (shooting) { // determines when the player hits the shoot button
    laser.visible = true; // display the laser
    for (var i=0; i<20; i++) { // do this for all of 20 enAry[num] objects
        if (laser.hitTestObject(enAry[i])) {
            stage.removeChild(enAry[i]); // remove the enAry[num]
            pts = pts+5; // plus the player's points
        }
    }
} else {
    laser.visible = false;
}
```

Then I try to find out which enAry[num] is can't be hit by the laser. I add `trace(i);` before I do `removeChild`. Then I order all of its results from 0. And what I got is the `17` is not on the list. But another num included in the list (0 to 16 and 18 to 19).

How could that happens? And how can I fix that?

**Here's the code before I try to fix it using the code above**

```
// ......
// add the enAry[n]
// ......
addChild(enAry[n])
```

And at the enter frame event

```
removeChild(enAry[i])
```

Then I add the `stage.` to `addChild` and `removeChild` to set the `stage` to `enAry[num]`'s parent.

I took second try by using trace. After I order the number, I got this : `0,0,0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19` (duplicate 0 and 3).

At the first try I got this : `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19` (blank at 17).

Comment: **1.** You forgot to remove your object from the `enAry` array after removing it from the display list ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33439823/2256820)). **2.** To avoid the #2025 error, try always to do : `obj.parent.removeChild(obj);` ([for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016602/2256820)) ...

Comment: Yeah, most likely it's because you did not removed it from the array. The next Problem you will get is an array out of bounds error - you loop for 20 times but when you would remove a movieclip from your array the array would become shorter and enAry[20] would trow an exception. So you will need a i--; after you remove something from your array

Comment: Thanks to you guys! @akmozo

Comment: @Philarmon user limit lol